# R Shiny: create reactiveValues object with input$ values

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I would like to create a `reactiveValues` object in Shiny whose contents are defined the values contained in input widgets. I managed to do it, but my implementation seems to be unnecessarily clunky:

1. Create an empty `reactiveValues` object
2. Monitor when the value of input widgets changes with `observeEvent`
3. Assign values to the `reactiveValues` object using the non-reactive values from input widgets (`isolate`)

Here is an example:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
        column(2, radioButtons("main", label = "Main dish", choices = list("salad", "pasta"))),
        column(2, radioButtons("desert", label = "Desert", choices = list("fruit", "cake"))),
        column(8, actionButton("extra", "Louder!", style="background-color: #ffdb99"))
    ),
    verbatimTextOutput("myorder")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    # 1. Create reactiveValues object
    menuR <- reactiveValues()

    # 2. Update values whenever widgets change
    observeEvent(c(input$main, input$desert),
        menuR[["meal"]] <- paste(c(isolate(input$main), isolate(input$desert)), collapse = " & ")
    )

    # 3. Perform operations on object values
    observeEvent(input$extra,
        menuR[["meal"]] <- paste0(toupper(menuR[["meal"]]), "!!!")
    )

    output$myorder <- renderText(menuR[["meal"]])
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I would very much like to create the `reactiveValues` object directly like this (greatly simplifies the code above):

```
# Set values upon creation
menuR <- reactiveValues(meal = paste(c(input$main, input$desert), collapse = " & "))
```

which does not work because `input$main` is reactive...

I would have guessed that defining `reactiveValues` objects with values obtained from widgets would be a common thing to do.

Am I missing something?

Thanks for your help,

Hugo

Comment: Why do you must use `reactiveValue`? In your case, just put `input$main` and `input$desert` in the `renderText` is fine.

Comment: Hi Jim. My intent in a real world application is to have the `reactiveValues`object be a data frame whose contents can be modified through the inputs of several widgets on the fly. The text example was a simplification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by using `reactive()` instead of `reactiveValues()`. `menuR` is a reactive object that depends on the input values of `main` and `desert`. You can use it by calling `menu()` in your server code once it is defined. Also, this saves you from using `isolate()` as you can set the value of `menu` as a reactive object inside `observeEvent()`.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(2, radioButtons("main", label = "Main dish", choices = list("salad", "pasta"))),
    column(2, radioButtons("desert", label = "Desert", choices = list("fruit", "cake"))),
    column(8, actionButton("extra", "Louder!", style="background-color: #ffdb99"))
  ),
  verbatimTextOutput("myorder")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  menuR <- reactive({
    paste(c(input$main, input$desert), collapse = " & ")
  })

  observeEvent(
    input$extra,
    menuR <- reactive({
      toupper(paste(c(input$main, input$desert), collapse = " & "))
    })
  )

  output$myorder <- renderText(menuR())

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Edit**

I misunderstood the problem earlier. You can use `eventReactive()` which monitors a input and changes when the user input changes. I have also added a default value for when the action button is yet to be clicked by the user.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(2, radioButtons("main", label = "Main dish", choices = list("salad", "pasta"))),
    column(2, radioButtons("desert", label = "Desert", choices = list("fruit", "cake"))),
    column(8, actionButton("extra", "Louder!", style="background-color: #ffdb99"))
  ),
  verbatimTextOutput("myorder")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # Set a 'default' value for the output
  default.menuR <- reactive({
    paste(c(input$main, input$desert), collapse = " & ")
  })

  menuR <- eventReactive(input$extra, {
    toupper(paste(c(input$main, input$desert), collapse = " & "))
  })

  # Initial state of the button is 0, which displays 'default' value
  output$myorder <- renderText({
    if (input$extra == 0) {
      return(default.menuR())
    }
    menuR()
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Vishesh. Unfortunately, I also require that the reactive object can be modified on the fly by several widgets, which your code does not do (the app never displays the uppercase text generated by `toupper()`). I believe that is because the `menuR` object containing uppercase text only exists within the `observeEvent` function.

Comment: Please let me know if the edited solution worked for you.

Comment: Yes it does. Thank you Vishesh.

Answer (score 0):

I have taken Vishesh's suggestion and made it work. It does not look much different than my original example, and still requires repeating several lines of code.
It works by over-writing the reactive object each time one of the widgets changes.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
        column(2, radioButtons("main", label = "Main dish", choices = list("salad", "pasta"))),
        column(2, radioButtons("dessert", label = "dessert", choices = list("fruit", "cake"))),
        column(8, actionButton("extra", "Louder!", style="background-color: #ffdb99"))
    ),
    verbatimTextOutput("myorder")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    menuR <- reactive({
        paste(c(input$main, input$dessert), collapse = " & ")
    })

    # Render text when app loads
    output$myorder <- renderText(menuR())

    # Update reactive object and re-render text (button 'extra')
    observeEvent(
        input$extra,{
            temp <- toupper(paste(c(input$main, input$dessert), collapse = " & "))
            menuR <<- reactive(temp)
            output$myorder <- renderText(menuR())
        }
    )

    # Update reactive object and re-render text (button 'main' or 'dessert')
    observeEvent(c(input$main, input$dessert),{
        menuR <- reactive(paste(c(input$main, input$dessert), collapse = " & "))
        output$myorder <- renderText(menuR())
    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```